# how to store € in Oracle WE8ISO8859P1

Tags: oracle

We have a customer who wants to store '€' symbol through our application in Oracle VARCHAR2 column. Their database characterset is WE8ISO8859P1.

Our customer does does not want to change their database characterset to WE8MSWIN1252 which supports  '€' symbol storage.

And we do not want to change the data type to NVARCHAR in the short term.

Is there any easy way to go around this to store € in Oracle WE8ISO8859P1?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems to me that the choices are to change the character set to `WE8MSWIN1252` or to change the data type of the column to `NVARCHAR2`. If your application is a web application then you might be able to store `€` as `&#8364;` or `&euro;`.

Comment: `WE8ISO8859P15` supports the € currency symbol.

Comment: Yes, you can change from `WE8ISO8859P1` to `WE8ISO8859P15` but there are [a couple of small changes associated with that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15#Changes_from_ISO-8859-1). The only changes associated with going from `WE8ISO8859P1` to `WE8MSWIN1252` is that some control characters in the former are display characters in the latter -- that is, existing display characters won't be changed as they would moving from `WE8ISO8859P1` to `WE8ISO8859P15`.

Comment: The funny thing is, if you don't do any transcoding (your NLS setting on the client and in the database is the same) things will work perfectly "well" - although the representation in the database is incorrect. The euro-sign will be displayed correctly. Something to watch out for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, this character set is older than euro. you can upgrade to WE8ISO8859P15 or try to use unused hex values 80–9F (*CHR(128)*-*CHR(159)*), then you'd have to replace them on client...

other possibility is to store UTF-8 encoded text as its representation